# Passing values through intnet and Bundle Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bundle

I have been trying to pass a coordinate from one activity to another, a latitude, and a longitude. In my Activity1 I have:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FindLocation.this, FinalRestaurant.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putDouble ("LocationLat", currentMarkerLocation.latitude);
extras.putDouble ("LocationLng", currentMarkerLocation.longitude);
intent.putExtras(extras);

Toast.makeText(FindLocation.this, currentMarkerLocation.latitude + ", " + currentMarkerLocation.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In my second Activity, I have:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
lat = bundle.getDouble("LocationLat");
lng = bundle.getDouble("LocationLng");

Toast.makeText(FinalRestaurant.this, lat + ", " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My app just crashes and doesn't go to the second Activity because the bundle is null. Exact error:  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.os.Bundle.getDouble(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

I have tried without a bundle and with a bundle and nothing seems to work and if I used a default value, It would always go to that value. If there is another way to do this or if I am doing something wrong, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does the crash logs in stack trace say?

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.os.Bundle.getDouble(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the startActivity () with the same intent you created?

Comment: yes I am here is how I am calling it.

startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling startActivity you are just calling it with a new intent without passing the bundle to it.

So **don't call** it like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
```

Call it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FindLocation.this, FinalRestaurant.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putDouble ("LocationLat", currentMarkerLocation.latitude);
extras.putDouble ("LocationLng", currentMarkerLocation.longitude);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);  // Pass Intent created here
```